# Error handling in ng5

Tags: angular, angular5

I am new to angular and I ma using version 5 to develop a small feature.
I have a register component and in that I have register method as below that is called upon a click event of a button.

```
register()
  {
    this.authService.register(this.model).subscribe(m=>{
      //console.log("Registeration Successful");
      this.alertify.success("Registeration Successful");
     }, error => {
       console.log(error);
       //console.log("Error while registering.");
       this.alertify.error(error);
     });
  }
```

In service I have two methods that calls API successfully but I am getting error 
`CatchSubscriber.AuthService.errorHandler`. This is probably due to the catch. I want to 
get the errors from API and I need to show those errors in user interface.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpRequest, HttpDownloadProgressEvent, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


register(model: any)
{
    const httpheaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-type','application/json');
    return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl + 'Register', model, {headers: httpheaders, responseType: 'json' }).catch(this.errorHandler);
}


private errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse)
{
  console.error(error.message);
  return Observable.throw(error.message || 'Server Error');
}
```

The error I am facing is

```
TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.throw is not a function
"CatchSubscriber.AuthService.errorHandler"
 at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:105)

at MapSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:134)

at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:108)
 at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:134)

at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:108)
```

I have checked other [links](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1866), [otherLinks](https://github.com/hasanhameed07/angular2-dashboard-starter/issues/3) as well and  tried the same but I am still facing this error

Answer (score 0):

Use `catchError` not `catch`. Your register method would look like:

```
register(model: any)
{
    const httpheaders = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-type','application/json');
    return this.httpClient
        .post(this.baseUrl + 'Register', model, {headers: httpheaders, responseType: 'json' })
        .pipe(catchError(this.errorHandler));
}
```